# Showing a function $\notin L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Q) Let $F(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)dt$ for $x\in (0,\infty)$. If $f>0, f\in L^1$, show that $F\notin L^1$.

My attempt:

Since $f\in L^1$, $\int_0^x f(t)dt<\infty$ for all $x\in (0,\infty)$

$$\int_0^\infty |F(x)|dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}\bigg|\int_0^x f(t)dt\bigg| = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x f(t)dt \text{ since $f>0$ } \\
=\int_0^\infty \int_t^\infty \frac{f(t)}{x}dxdt \text{ By Fubini's } \\
=\int_0^\infty f(t)\log x\bigg|_t^\infty dt = \infty
$$

Hence $F\notin L^1$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you have $F(x)\underset{+\infty}{\sim}\frac{\|f\|_1}{x}$ which is not integrable.

Comment: I see, may I know what that notation means? Thanks.

Comment: The quotient $\frac{F(x)}{\|f\|_1/x}$ tends to 1 as x tends to infinity, where $0<\|f\|_1 = \int_0^\infty f$. In other words, as x tends to infinity $F(x)$ is roughly of the form $C/x$ for some positive constant $C$.